Why does disk management see an external USB SSD, but also says it is offline?
I have an Orico M.2 SSD enclosure (M2PV-C3-BK-EP-CA) using the Realtek RTL9210B controller. I have put a Samsung 990 Pro 4TB SSD inside it (NVMe). Both are brand new.
I am running Windows 10. The enclosure is recognized, and it seems to see the disk as Disk Management has labelled it Disk 4.  But, it indicates it is Not Initialized.
When I first plugged it in (and the several times I tried again) it asked to Initialize it, but then threw the Virtual Disk Manager error "Incorrect function" when I tried. When I right click, the initialization option is greyed out, and it is listed as offline.  If I click on offline, it again throws the "Incorrect function" error.
If I use the CMD started DISKPART function, it says it is Online, if I turn it offline it disappears from the DISKPART disk list, and I can't try to turn it back online (i.e. I tried to turn it off and on again, which didn't work).
The enclosure says it works with NVMe, and says it can handle a 4TB drive, so it - theoretically - should work. The SSD looks seated correctly in the housing, the silicon plug has it securely in place.
As a note, I cannot test the SSD in my computer as this 2020 machine apparently doesn't do NVMe.


I have an Orico M.2 SSD enclosure (M2PV-C3-BK-EP-CA) using the Realtek RTL9210B controller. I have put a Samsung 990 Pro 4TB SSD inside it (NVMe).
The enclosure says it works with NVMe, and says it can handle a 4TB drive, so it - theoretically - should work. The SSD looks seated correctly in the housing, the silicon plug has it securely in place.

The enclosure you purchased only supports a maximum of 2TB not 4TB.



You will need to get a different enclosure. One that indicates support for 4TB disks. The controller is responsible for negotiating the size of the disk.
One of the reasons you were unable to initialize the disk is because the controller doesn’t support 4TB disks. Windows is requesting you initialize the disk due to the fact it doesn’t have a file system.
Source: ORICO-M2PV-C3

If you do manage to initialize the disk, as Ramhound has noted it will work, but you'll lose half the disk.  I believe the reason the initialize is failing is also due to the size mismatch.  The enclosure reports 2TB to Windows but Windows also queries the PCI Vendor Code which is returning the 4TB size.

@kato42 - So return it, but Amazon is known not to verify product descriptions, enter by sellers (they literally cannot) but they will accept a defective or product with an incorrect specification. It took me less than 1 minute to verify the problem. I don’t go off Amazon descriptions unless I can verify the specification
